# How to calculate the distance of each cluster in a scatter plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have 2 clusters plotted in a scatter plot and i need to find their standard deviation and distance from the center from one cluster to another. I was not able to find any guide of documentation that simplifies the process of finding the center of 2 clusters for scatter plots, the reason is that i need to compare the scatter of each cluster with the distance of the centres of the clusters. My actual scatter plot looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


vector1 = [
    2.8238, 
    3.0284, 
    5.9333,
    2.0156,
    2.2467, 
    2.0092,
    4.7983, 
    4.3554,
    3.6372, 
    1.3159, 
    2.6174, 
    2.2336, 
    0.9625, 
    5.6285, 
    5.4040, 
    2.7887, 
    0, 
    3.4632, 
    0, 
    2.7370
]  
vector5 = [
    1.2994, 
    7.4469,
    3.6503, 
    2.1667,
    4.1975, 
    3.3006, 
    10.4082, 
    3.4112, 
    2.2395, 
    1.5653, 
    4.3237, 
    1.8679, 
    1.2622, 
    14.1372, 
    6.1686, 
    3.8903, 
    2.2873, 
    6.2559, 
    0.2132, 
    7.2303,
]

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 10.0)
plt.style.use('ggplot')
data = [vector1, std_colomns4]

plt.plot(vector1 , marker='.', linestyle='none', markersize=20, label='Vector 1')
plt.plot(vector5, marker='.', linestyle='none', markersize=20, label='Vector 5')


plt.xticks(range(1, 20, 1))
plt.yticks(range(1, 20, 1))
plt.ylabel('Sizes')
plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

For the sake of pre-visualization:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if my answer is adequate. Your question is poorly explained currently. Add more details to it

Comment: You got it right for the most part, i need to visualize the distance and is the means of the standard deviation of the cluster in each direction

Comment: Your wording is still unclear to me. You need to give some example to make it more clear.

Comment: I want to iterate inside my array grab the mean value from the indices inside my array, for both arrays that should be the center of my cluster and then use those two means and calculate their standard deviation which will be the distance

Comment: I wanna pick the mean value from vector1, mean value from vector 2 and calculate their standard deviation

Comment: I have added some modifications to the answer. `mean1` (orange horizontal line) is the mean of `vector1` and `mean5` (blue horizontal line)  is the mean of `vector5`. Now what distances do you want to plot. Perhaps now you can explain better by looking at the figure in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the mean by converting them to arrays

```
vector1 = np.array([...])
vector5 = np.array([...])

mean1 = np.mean(vector1)
mean5 = np.mean(vector5)

# Rest of the code

plt.plot((vector1+vector5)/2, marker='x', linestyle='none', markersize=12, label='Mean')

plt.axhline(mean1)
plt.axhline(mean5, c='b')
```

[image]